# How to display multiple records in single feature point using ArcMap 10.x?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, display

I have a list of touristic sights in a point layer (around 500 records). Each record has a spatial location field - municipality (town, city). In many cases there are more than one sights in a single municipality. I need to display them in a map of 1 : 100 000 scale.
So, logically, if I displayed them in a normal way, the dots would be overlapping (one city - many dots).

Is there any feasible and cartographically common way to do this?
What came to my mind:

1. having only one dot in the map which would say upon clicking/hovering on it there are many records in that spot
2. maybe there's a setting that will keep the dots from overlapping, perhaps spreading them in a circle or something along this way?

(I'm not sure how to correctly state the question in the title, please, if you can edit it so it is more understandable, do so)

Comment: How about creating a heatmap?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how a heatmap would help me with my problem?

Comment: By displaying a fat coloured blob, where a lot of points are, and displaying smaller blobs or simple points where few or only one point is.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. I don't think that will help me as I need to distinctively display all the dots for each sightseeing place. But thank you.

Comment: The arcgis equivalent of @MyGIS 's answer is called [clustering of points layer](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-clustering.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Use Point displacement or Point cluster from symbology menu. You need QGIS 3.x .
Also check this page; there is a nice [video](https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/13/even-more-aggregations-qgis-point-cluster-renderer/)

Comment: I work in Arcmap 10.x. I'm uploading it to Portal for Arcgis after that. So QGIS might not be the way. BUt I'll look into that.

Comment: My answer is then irrelevant. I have added the ArcMap tag so others do not get confused. Thank you for the clarification.